# Shorter imports not working in react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im using create-react-app with typescript template and I wanted to shorten my imports by configuring my `tsconfig.json`:

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**Import:**
[image]

**However it throws me an error:**
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@components/PasswordTip/PasswordTip' in ...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Was this project created using "create-react-app"? If yes, they have an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12047) regarding this.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned that in the question.

Comment: My bad. Anyway, they have an open issue as linked above.